# Inconveniente al cargar una valor de tipo Double con decimal

Tags: c#, mysql, double

Un `textbox` arroja el valor `0.7` mediante la propiedad `.text`, ejecutando un `Convert.ToDouble(txt.text)` Este convierte el string en un numero de tipo `Double` con este valor `0.7` (Hasta aquí todo correcto), Pero cuando este valor lo meto dentro de la base de datos que espera obtener valores de tipo `Double` carga un entero con el valor de `7` así mismo si cargo el valor a mano en la base de datos el valor lo toma correctamente.

> Simplificare parte del código que no hace falta mostrar para que sea menos engorroso

Funcion que llama ala rutina con la cual hago la carga en la base de datos:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = path;
            conn.Open();
        }
        string query = "CALL `Routine_AgregarNuevoValor_Materiales`( '" + _Espesor + "'");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Rutina en la base de datos:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `stock de materias primas` (`Espesor`) VALUES (Espesor);
END
```

¿Cual es el inconveniente y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Ese 7 a que te refieres? lo convierte a 7 de 0.7?

Comment: Exactamente eso si

Comment: Trata asi a ver si es eso string query = "CALL `Routine_AgregarNuevoValor_Materiales`( " + _Espesor + "");

Comment: Problema resuelto, muchas gracias

Comment: Tenes luz verde Edgar, aguardo la respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola el detalle pienso que esta en la forma en la que estas concatenando esta parte.

```
string query = "CALL `Routine_AgregarNuevoValor_Materiales`( '" + _Espesor + "'");
```

Ya que al tener **( '" + _Espesor + "'");** lo que hará sera volverlo un `string` por los ' ' que le pones antes, pienso que por eso te lo vuelve un entero.

Podría resolverse solo poniéndolo de la siguiente manera.

```
string query = "CALL Routine_AgregarNuevoValor_Materiales( " + _Espesor + "");
```

Así el dato que ya convertiste en Double te debería de respetar el formato.

Saludos